# Microsoft SSMS User password

Tags: database, visual-studio, ssms

I'm trying to connect Visual Studio to my local database using Microsoft SSMS, but when I try to create a new user, his password isn't what I have chosen. I have also tried modifying the "sa" user, but nothing helped because password is always the same and I can't get it. I want a user so I can connect my DB to Visual studio using SQL authentification. How could I change the user password?

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: What do you mean that their password isn't what they chose? How are you determining that? Are you trying to connect and getting an error? What is the error in the logs if you did?

Comment: I was trying to connect with credentials, but I have kept getting an error where it said that I don't have permission doing what I wanted, probably because credentials were wrong...I also tried running SSMS as an administrator but that didn't help so I just chose another connection method and it worked as I mentioned in my own answer. All users are on local so I created all of them so I was sure I know the password and typing the right data.

Comment: That doesn't sound like you were getting the password wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using another method...i connected using Windows authentication instead so I didn't have to write credentials for any user, but just send server name